# How to make footer stuck to the bottom, and keep a minimum distance to the other content

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS, and am having some problems with my footer. I have really tried to find an answer, but nothing seems to work.

I need to have the footer at the very bottom of the page, but in the same time have a minimum distance to the other content of 150px.

So far I have managed to get the footer at the bottom, but I can't get the minimum distance to work.

```html
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">

        <div class="banner">

            <h1></h1>

        </div>

        <div class="navbar">

             <ul>
                 <li><a id="home" class="active" href="home.html">Hjem</a></li>
                 <li><a id="billeder" href="billeder.html">Billeder</a></li>
                 <li><a id="video" href="video.html">Video</a></li>
                 <li><a id="kontakt" href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
             </ul>

         </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bodybill">

        <div class="content">
                <p class="welcome">Some text.</p>
        </div>
  
  <div class="leftpic">
  </div>
  
  <div class="rightpic">
  </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

             <footer>Some text</footer>

    </div>
</div> 

</body>
```

```html
html,body {
     background-image: url("image.png");
     height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
}

div.wrapper {
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     width:100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}

div.header {
     padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
div.bodybill {
     padding:0px;
  height: 600px;
     padding-bottom: 100px;
}


div.footer {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background: black;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
     border-color: #141953;
     background-image: url("image.png");
     bottom: 0;
}

footer {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done simply, but I noticed that you're doing it the hard way.

You can create a new div and name it `.wrap` and wrap it to the whole body content, except the `.footer`

and in your CSS, do this:

```
.wrap {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}
```

Comment: We wrapped the body content in a wrapper and gave it a minimum height so that even if the content's height is less than the height we gave, it gives it the height we defined. 100vh is like 100% Viewport Height. We're telling the browser to fill the .wrap 100% in view port. and we used the calc(100vh - 150px); is because your footer will go below the viewport when your value is 100vh. Since your footer was 150px height.  We said 100vh - 150px, so that the footer showup and sticks below. Hope I explained you well, forgive me if I confused you and bad at explaining :P

Comment: No it made sence :) But when I'm going to another monitor with higher res, the footer is not 100% at the bottom, is there any way to compensate for that, maybe with % instead of px?

Comment: It should look same on all viewport. What's the resolution? and what 100%? height or width?

Comment: The resolution is 1920 x 1080. Sorry, 100% should probably not be used in this case. What I meant was that there is a small gap under the footer. The issue is that the footer makes a scroller even though the space between footer and content is more than the 150px, so when I try to move it up, it makes the gap under. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: 100vh is the 100% height from top to bottom of the view port. the -150px is the height of the footer. If your footer height is less than or higher than 150px, change it to that certain number and it should work fine. when we give 100vh to the .wrap, it's occupying the full height of view port. when you do the calc -footer height, it gives the room for footer to come up.

Answer (score 0):

Since your footer is inside of your wrapper and your wrapper is set to 100% height. Add

```
div.wrapper{
display:block;
}
```

to the wrapper div. Everything else can stay the same. And to your footer div you could change your position property to:

```
div.footer{
position: relative;
margin-top: 150px;
}
```

The rest could stay the same. This will position the footer div relative to the wrapper div which it is in. The margin-top pushes all content above the footer div 150 pixels away.